# How to reuse the CI/CD pipeline from another repo, but add one extra job?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a complete `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file which includes stages and jobs in repo A.

In repo B, I wish to reuse all of this, but add one job in an existing stage. Repo B's `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
include:
  - project: 'mygroup/repo-a'
    ref: master
    file: '.gitlab-ci.yml'

extra_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "hello world"
```

But this only gave me the same CI/CD pipeline as seen in repo A. The new `extra_job` job is nowhere to be seen.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you define the stages?

Comment: The ”build” stage is a default stage you don't have to define. But I've tried using a stage already defined in the included .yml and it yields the same results.

Comment: Maybe you can do it differently, use pipeline and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the job did not appear, because I did not specify rules.

This was the solution:

```yaml
include:
  - project: 'mygroup/repo-a'
    ref: master
    file: '.gitlab-ci.yml'

extra_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "hello world"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

Comment: Nice! I wonder if you could also remove some extra hashes? Like docker's custom "!reset" yaml tag?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add this:

```
stages:
  - include
  - extra_job

include:
  script: do tigger

extra_job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "hello world"
```

[image]